# Using RDBMS for Users and Link with NoSQL Items

Tags: php, database, database-design, nosql, rdbms

I am planning an application and wish to maintain a **relational database and other non-relational**, respectively, MySQL and MongoDB.

One fact is that in relational database are maintained users, and non-relational, is maintained by **this user generated content**, where involves **geo queries**.

The problem now is how to **create a link between user and your item**s using both databases and maintaining the performance or am adopting the wrong approach?

My idea is to create a product table with a *foreign key* to the user in mysql and *objectId* of the product in the database non-relational.

Example MySQL Table:

```
table: products_relationship

| account_id | product_objectid                 |
| ---------- | -------------------------------- |
| 1          | 0b694fc34c9663883a5d4b32371f8333 |
| 1          | 0b694fc34c9663883a5d4b32371f9837 |
| 2          | 0b694fc34c9663883a5d4b32371f9bfc |
| 5          | 0b694fc34c9663883a5d4b32371fcb5f |
| 1          | 0b694fc34c9663883a5d4b32371fd809 |
```

So, the user at account_id = 1 has a first name, email and other data. And owns 3 products.

**Should I adopt a new methodology? I'll be gaining performance with that? Am I losing the functionality of NoSQL with that?**

Comment: You might be better of using a relational datastore and a key value cache to increase performance (read through cache paradigm). I get the sense that you are unnecessarily complicating things by storing some data in one platform and the rest in another.

Comment: Yes, this was my one doubt that if I am erring on the methodology that will take. But in my business, the performance should be the best possible and I need of geo queries that MongoDB gives me. I'm still wrong to use 2 databases?

Comment: Mysql does have [geospatial support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-gis-conformance-and-compatibility.html).

Comment: Only the InnoDB and not a good geospatial support. I really liked MongoDB geospatial, but it's a problem now to relationship with a Relational database. Sad.

Answer (score 1):

I work on a system at work that does just this. We have relational databases and NoSQL databases and we use a product called Mule (http://www.mulesoft.org/) to integrate them.

I would strongly recommend picking either MySQL or Mongo and doing all your PHP work against one of those databases. You can move data in near real time from MySQL->Mongo or from Mongo->MySQL. Mule is good at that.

You aren't going to be able to efficiently do "joins" across systems.

Mule will also help you do transformations on the data when you move it. As an example, you can take normalized data in MySQL and denormalize it for storing in Mongo.

Comment: I've liked Mule, but I don't want a generic software. +1 for a solution, but not mine

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I adopted a complex architecture while I did not need much complexity. There is no reason for me to want my users are in relational databases. Yes they can stay within the MongoDB without any problem, and the products within each user. This is a relationship that I create.

If I want, I can make the connection using _objectId